# Error running aspnet_regiis.exe -iru in cmd prompt

Tags: .net, iis, cmd

It gives me this when I try to run aspnet_regiis.exe -iru in my CMD prompt;

> This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.
>   Administators should then install/uninstall ASp.NET 4.5 with IIS8
>   using the "Turn Windows feature On/Off" dialog, the Server Managment
>   Tool or the dism.exe command line tool.

I have Win 8 and IIS 7.5 installed. I needed this so that I could remove this error:

> Could not load type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule' from assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Thank you

P.S. I am running cmd as Admin from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319